# How restore a specific database from backup using mongorestore command

Tags: mongodb

I created a backup of all my databases using mongodump command. Now I want to restore a specific database using mongorestore command.

How is this possible, I use this command: --db option then mongodb doesn't restore a specific database.

Answer (score 103):

To restore a single database you need to provide the path to the dump directory as part of the `mongorestore` command line.

For example:

```
# Backup the training database
mongodump --db training

# Restore the training database to a new database called training2
mongorestore --db training2 dump/training
```

The `--db` option for `mongodump` specifies the source database to dump.

The `--db` option for `mongorestore` specifies the target database to restore into.

Answer (score 20):

Use the following command to restore mongo db:

```
mongorestore -d dbname dbpath
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$ mongorestore --drop -d <database-name> <dir-of-backup-files>
```

- `--drop` Drop is necessary if you are replacing an existing db
- `-d <database-name>` The name of the database to create/replace
- `<dir-of-backup-files>` For some reason this is necessary even if it's the current directory

[image]

Reference: https://coderwall.com/p/3hx06a/restore-a-mongodb-database-mongorestore

Answer (score 1):

## Restoring using mongorestore

After making sure that `mongod` and `mongo` are running, go to the dump's parent directory in a new terminal. And use the command `mongorestore dump`. Where `dump` is the folder name in which the database dump is present.

[image: Restoring using mongorestore]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slightly unrelated, but based on the answers here i got the following

Using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#options) and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#options) archive feature I comprised a oneliner:

`mongodump --host H --port P --username U --password PWD --archive | mongorestore --username U1 --password PWD1 --archive`

The above example will :

1. Dump data from host `H` with port `P` logged in with user `U` and password `PWD`
2. "Stream" that data into your local database with user `U1` and password `PWD1`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are restoring from an archive, `--db` won't work.

From the [mongodb docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--db):

> The use of `--db` and `--collection` options are deprecated when restoring
> from a directory or an archive file.

So if you are restoring from an archive (`--archive`) you should add this:

```bash
--nsFrom="ORIGINAL_DB_NAME.*" --nsTo="NEW_DB_NAME.*"
```