# How restore from .gz backup with new database name using mongorestore r3.2.9?

Tags: backup, mongodb, restore

I'm trying to backup/restore mongodb database to/from .gz files as [sample script here](https://github.com/namgivu/mongodb-start/blob/master/01.backup-restore.sh)

```
#01 create .gz backup - ok for r3.2.9 and r3.4.10 
mongodump --db ${DB_NAME} --gzip --archive=${BACKUP_FILE_GZ}

#02 restore from .gz file - NOT ok for r3.2.9
mongorestore --gzip --archive=${BACKUP_FILE_GZ} --nsFrom "${DB_NAME}.*" --nsTo "${DB_NAME_RESTORE}.*"
```

Step 01 i.e. back up is good for both mongodb version `r3.2.9` and `r3.4.10`; though step 02 NOT works for `r3.2.9`

How can I get **mongorestore** version `r3.2.9` to restore from .gz file and be able to rename the database?

p.s.

We have the [solution here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114344/52550) but that requires the backup to be a folder; my backup files are huge i.e. 1Gb-2Gb so the extraction is too much time-consuming.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With 3.2.x you cannot use `--nsFrom` or `--nsTo` parameters. This pair of commands should work in all versions:

```
mongodump --db ${DB_NAME} --gzip -o ${BACKUP_FILE_GZ}

mongorestore --gzip --db "${DB_NAME_RESTORE}" ${BACKUP_FILE_GZ}/${DB_NAME}
```

Now you get a directory with gzipped files and you can restore all (or just one) collections to a different database.

Answer (score 25):

> Nothing works for me but this.

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=/path/to/file.gz --db db_name
```

Comment: The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}

Answer (score 3):

That is because your mongodump script has an `--archive` flag.

Then you have to use it when doing mongorestore.

Comment: Normally, answers here require a bit more than a one-liner. Perhaps you might point to OP to some documentation about this issue or similar? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
mongorestore --gzip --db {DB_NAME} --collection {COLLECTION_NAME} ./{FILENAME}.bson.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

For version 6 You only need to run:
(Suppose that your current directory has a backup file named backup_db.gzip and you want to create a database named blog from its content)

```
 mongorestore --gzip --archive=./backup_db.gzip  blog
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore more than one collection at once, use this command below:

```shell
for file in *.gzip; do mongorestore --gzip --archive=$file <database_name>; done
```

Replace the `<database_name>` with your database name. This works for me.

You can use, also, the `--verbose` option to see all logs